# CSS How to add custom button in current theme?

Tags: html, css, html-framework-7

I'm using Mobix theme, and I need to add some custom button.

http://sindevo.com/mobix/#!/blog.html

What I want is something like this picture actually the three button Green, Yellow, and Purple.

[image]

This theme based on Framework7 but I can't find how I can do like what I want.

So far I add this code

```
<div style="position:absolute;">
<a href="#" class="button button-fill color-blue">Tes A</a>
</div>
```

after `<div class="post_title">.....</div>` and here is the result.

[image]

Just trying sindevo answer but still the same.

[image]

```
                      <div class="post_entry">
                      <div class="post_date">
                        <span class="day">#{{ $queue->id}}</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="post_title">
                      <h2><a href="{{ route('operator.antrian.show', $queue->id )}}">{{ $queue->no_kendaraan }}</a></h2>
                      </div>
                      <div class="buttons_container">
                        <a href="#" class="button button-fill color-green" style="width:15%;">Tes A</a>
                        <a href="#" class="button button-fill color-yellow" style="width:15%;">Tes B</a>
                        <a href="#" class="button button-fill color-purple" style="width:15%">Tes C</a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
```

Here is my css

```
.post_title{
width:15%;
float:left;
margin:0 0 0 10%;
}
.buttons_container{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 5%;
}
```

Anyway there is no margin in my button, but its fill the entire block. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: This sounds like you're asking someone else to create these buttons for you. Why don't you try creating them yourself, and if you're having trouble getting them to look right, then come back and ask a more concise question.

Comment: @HaydenSchiff edited.

Answer (score 0):

//use table and then place the button (button class="form_submit") as u need in table section

```
<ul class="responsive_table">
                 <li class="table_row">
                    <div class="table_section_14">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="table_section_14">Medium</div>
                    <div class="table_section_14">Business</div>
                    <div class="table_section_14">Deluxe</div>  
                 </li>
                  <li class="table_row">
                    <div class="table_section_14">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="table_section_14">Medium</div>
                    <div class="table_section_14">Business</div>
                    <div class="table_section_14">Deluxe</div>  
                 </li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the structure of a blog posts code:

```
<div class="post_entry">
    <div class="post_date">
        <span class="day">24</span>
        <span class="month">january</span>
    </div>
    <div class="post_title">
        <h2><a href="blog-single.html">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste accusantium.</a></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

You need to:

**1.** In style.css make the post_title smaller in width

```
.post_title{
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 10%;
}
```

Let's say width:50%;

**2.** Then build a new DIV container with your buttons

```
<div class="buttons_container"></div>
    <a href="#">button</a>
    <a href="#">button</a>
    <a href="#">button</a>
</div>
```

**3.** In style.css add

```
.buttons_container{
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 5%;
}
```

**4.** Make sure the total amount of your blocks that are in that line do not pass 100%.

This requires basic CSS knowledge.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your .button class in CSS have float left.

Your 3 buttons should have float left in order to stay one after eachother.